# Hibernate HQL What is a correct syntax for negating the 'is' statement

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I cannot wrap my head around following problem:
I have declared a JPA entity having one Boolean field "shallBeDeleted"
This field is type of Boolean (not the primitive boolean). It may contain null value.

In my HQL i want to select users where shallBeDeleted is NOT true. means i want to get all rows, having  shallBeDeleted set to null or false

```
select new my.package.UserModel(
            u.uuid,d.userDataId,.....) 
            from User u left join u.userData d 
            where u.uuid = :id AND u.shallBeDeleted not true order by d.modified desc
```

This yields an error:

> "unexpected token: true"

Answer (score 2):

just use:

```
u.shallBeDeleted is null or u.shallBeDeleted = false
```

Comment: Or condition needs to be grouped for proper result. (u.shallBeDeleted is null or u.shallBeDeleted = false)